# Reading integer from a file in c++

Tags: c++

I have a text file named *in.txt* that has an integer in each line. The first line contains the number of lines minus 1 (=the number of integers). I want to read this integers into an array. So I wrote the below program :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::fstream myfile("in.txt");

    int number;
    int counter=0;
    myfile >> number;
    int inputArray[number];

    for(counter=0;counter=number;counter++)
    {
        myfile>>inputArray[counter];
    }

    for(counter=0;counter=number;counter++){
        printf("%i",inputArray[counter]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Q1 :** When I run it, nothing happens! A black screen appears and remains empty. What is wrong?

**Q2 :** If the input file was really big (Contains about 2^27 integers), is this program a good idea, or I must do something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code:

First of all, you fail to check if your input operations succeed. Do something like

```
if (! (myfile >> number)) {
       std::cerr << "Reading number failed!\n";
       return -1;
}
```

for every input operation. Else, you might use garbage values which might lead to strange and hard to find bugs.

Next, there are no variable sized arrays in C++, use `std::vector<int> inputArray(number);` instead. This will initialize the whole array to `0` which might cost some time, you could change your code to

```
std::vector<int> inputArray;
inputArray.reserve(number);
for(int64_t counter=0;counter<number;counter++)
{
    int temp;
    myfile>>temp;
    inputArray.push_back(temp);
}
```

to avoid that.

Last, your loop conditions are wrong. They should be

```
for(counter=0;counter<number;counter++)
```

If the number of numbers might be large, you should use a fixed sized integer like `int64_t` for you counters and `number`instead.

*Is this a good idea?* Well, it is an rather efficient way to read the numbers, but reading 2^27 numbers will always take a lot of time. If you can avoid doing this, it is your biggest opportunity to speed things up.

As a last remark, here is how I would write the input operation with error handling and all:

```
for (int temp; myFile >> temp;)
    inputArray.push_back(temp);

if( inputArray.size() != number) 
    std::cerr << "Number of numbers read did not match number in first line!\n";
```

Comment: `there are no variable sized arrays in C++` : Did I used variable sized array in my program? I replaced `=` with `<` character in for loops, and the program works fine now.

Comment: @Abraham `int inputArray[number];` is a VLA because `number` is no compile time constant. You can do this with `g++` and `clang++` because they support it as extension, but it is not standard C++.

Comment: In your suggestion code, does the integers store in Heap? What about my program?

Comment: @Abraham `std::vector` does store the numbers on the heap, I am not sure about the VLAs. I think they do not, which will be another problem if `number` gets large.

Comment: @BaummitAugen even assuming the implementation uses a doubling allocator it's still better to allocate once than many times. Also this could fail on the input, ideally you should switch to `while(myfile >> temp)` and then push back inside the loop

Comment: @Mgetz *"even assuming the implementation uses a doubling allocator it's still better to allocate once than many times."* Sure, never disagreed with that. I just doubt it will be a huge benefit bc IO usually dominates in tasks like this. *" Also this could fail on the input"* Yep, told him to check that in my first point, but added a checking example at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is a typo in this line:

```
for(counter=0;counter=number;counter++)
```

That should be:

```
for(counter=0; counter < number; counter++)
```

You have the same error in the next `for` loop.

Comment: Is this an efficient way to read about 2^27 integers from a file into an array? I want to sort the integers with merge sort algorithm. Is this efficient? Or I should use another procedure?

Comment: You might be able to speed things up quite a bit by reading the entire text into a string and using `istringstream`.

Comment: @RSahu: I've never heard of that being faster, I rather think that would be significantly _slower_.

Comment: @RSahu they still will have memory issues, they are reading in 2^29 bytes, rather they should consider loading part of the file at a time and sorting that

Comment: @Abraham use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and call either [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) or [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize). Also make sure to be on a 64bit machine... 32bit machines will have issues allocating that much ram. But more to the point that's way too much to allocate in most cases. You don't need to as you can do it piecemeal

Comment: @MooingDuck, simple testing under cygwin showed that both approaches take almost equal amount of time. My opinion was biased based on parsing of XML files using libxml.

Answer (score 1):

1. 1. You have to create a dynamic array to be able to choose it's size while executing the program

   2. An error in logical operator
   3. It's better to put weather you want an input or an output file when declaring my file

try this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::fstream myfile("in.txt", ios::in | ios::out);

    int number;
    int counter = 0;
    myfile >> number;
    int *inputArray = new int[number];

    for (counter = 0; counter != number; counter++){
        myfile >> inputArray[counter];
    }

    for (counter = 0; counter != number; counter++){
        printf("%i", inputArray[counter]);
    }
    delete[] inputArray;
    return 0;
}
```

I think binary files are better for huge amount of data.